# How can I create a Qt project without a UI/Designer file?

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like my project to be written programmatically instead of using Qt Designer.

EDIT:
I'm just asking for a template :P

Comment: Qt projects do not require the use of Qt Designer. Simply write whatever code you want. Create a MainWindow and add your widgets to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 2: I found out how, feel free to use the code down below:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

class MyWindow : public QDialog {
public:
    MyWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
};

MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle("MyWindow");

    // Make widgets, etc...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto win = new MyWindow;
    win->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This requirement has a very simple solution: Just do write your code programatically instead of using QtDesigner. :)